# How to get the window of a visio drawing using VBA to set the zoom to fit to the window?

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I am trying to make the zoom fit to window for a particular page in visio with vba.
appVisio is an variable name representing the visio application object,

```
appVisio.ActiveWindow.Zoom = -1
```

works, but I want to avoid using ActiveWindow, when I try appVisio.Windows(1) or appVisio.Window, it doesn't work becasue those two lines return a window of type visApplication, whereas the .ActiveWindow returns a window of type visDrawing, what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Visio windows have a property called ViewFit that does what you want. You can set it to visFitPage to fit to the page, or visFitWidth to just have it fit to just the width the of the page.

```
appVisio.ActiveWindow.ViewFit = visFitPage
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.